# Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, percona

I have just installed an Ubuntu Server 16.04 with Nginx, and i have installed php in this way:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-cli php7.0-cgi php7.0-fpm php7.0-curl
```

And for MySql i have installed percona, in this way:

```
apt-get install percona-server-server-5.7 percona-server-client-5.7
```

but I can't understand why i can't use PDO in my php script, this is my code:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=db;host=localhost;charset=utf8", "username", "password");
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver
```

I have searched online and I have found that i have to uncomment this line in Windows in php.ini:

```
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

or this line on Linux:

```
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.so
```

I have checked my php.ini in:

```
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
```

and i have a `.dll` file and not a `.so` file, I can't also understand why I have a dll instead of a so. Anyway enabling that .dll file and restarting php nothing change. Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying you have an actually `pdo_mysql.dll` file on your linux filesystem? Or are you just saying you could only find the `;extension=pdo_mysql.dll` comment in your php.ini file? Becuase the comments don't matter. They mean nothing. You just need to add that line to your php.ini.

Comment: I find only that line on my php.ini, so i have to add it? Or I have to install the package written in the answer below?

Comment: Right, the line you found in your php.ini file as a comment doesn't mean anything. It's just a comment. Whether you add the line or not you still need to install the correct package through your package manager or compile the extension yourself to load it in PHP. In your case that's going to be `php7.0-pdo-mysql`

Answer (score 2):

Installing the mysql client/server packages doesn't effect PHP. PHP still needs the bindings to talk to your mysql server, specifically in your case the PDO mysql driver.

The package is probably going to be called `php7.0-pdo-mysql` depending on which repositories are configured your Ubuntu package manager. If you're using PHP 7 on Ubuntu 16.04 it's more than likely going to be a meta package that includes `php7.0-mysql`. Here's what I got from aptitude on 16.04 using the Ondrej PPA.

`aptitude show php7.0-pdo-mysql`

```
Package: php7.0-mysql                    
State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Version: 7.0.9-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
Priority: optional
Section: php
Maintainer: Debian PHP Maintainers 
Architecture: amd64
Uncompressed Size: 514 k
Depends: php-common (>= 1:35), ucf, php7.0-common, libc6 (>= 2.15)
Provides: php-mysqli, php-mysqlnd, php-pdo-mysql, php7.0-mysqli, php7.0-mysqlnd, php7.0-pdo-mysql
Description: MySQL module for PHP
 This package provides the MySQL module(s) for PHP.
```

The `php7.0-pdo-mysql` is the one we're interested in for loading the mysql driver for PDO in PHP. So make sure to search your package manager to find the correct package before you attempt installing, but there should be a similar package for your distro/repositories.

Once installed you'll need to restart php-fpm, something like `sudo service php7.0-fpm restart` and then check your [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/phpinfo) to make sure the `pdo_mysql` driver is now loaded.

You shouldn't need to edit your php.ini manually when installing through your package manager. Also, adding the `extension=pdo_mysql.so` line to your php.ini has no effect if the extension doesn't exist. And obviously, trying to load dll won't work on linux, those are Windows-only libraries.

Comment: I recently upgraded a server to Ubuntu 16.04 and PHP7.1 and forgot to install the 7.1 version of the odbc driver. Thank you for the advice!